# Have any married couples been canonized at the same time?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, saint, canonization

There are countless saints in the Catholic Church, and while many of them have been celibate, some have been married (e.g. Thomas More, Elizabeth Ann Seaton).

Have any married couples been canonized at the same time? Specifically, I'm looking for saints who:

- Were formally canonized by the Apostolic See, rather than a local authority (so anyone following [Ulrich of Augsburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrich_of_Augsburg) in 993 AD)
- Were not recognized as a saint before that time (so Mary and Joseph don't count)
- Were not automatically classified as saints due to their martyrdom alone (something that is [not possible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/2234/16688) under the current rules established in 1983)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [Louis (1823-1894)](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5875) & [Zélie Martin (1831-1877)](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5880), parents of St. Thérèse of Lisieux, [were jointly canonized in October 2015](https://www.osv.com/osvnewsweekly/byissue/article/tabid/735/artmid/13636/articleid/17360/history-awaits-in-canonization-of-married-couple.aspx).

Comment: Wow, quite recent! The article you link to says they are the first married couple to be canonized jointly. I would have there were others in the last thousand years.

Comment: @Thunderforge That article claims they were the first, but I haven't verified that claim.